# numpy.maximum.reduce not returning maximum value

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Hi I am trying to find the maximum of binary masks for which I have used `numpy.maximum.reduce`. I have a set of binary masks and in order to find the maximum from all the masks(which according to me points to the most edges in the images) and avoid overlapping. Therefore I used `numpy.maximum.reduce` to find the max of all the binary pixels. But the result is not as expected. It is not showing the white regions as maximum and taking the gray regions for the final output mask(max). And to get the mask I have performed dilation and blurring of edge detected images. So will that affect the final result(meaning comparing the masks to find the most edges)?

**Q1.** Is it the right approach to find the maximum of the masks and avoid overlapping regions?

**Q2.** Will it return the regions with most edges?

**Q3.** Should I use the masks or the original edge detected images for getting the most edges?

[Results of combining masks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBYHZ.jpg)
[Individual Masked Images](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qecYT5INs0OnpGETpLizzNDScalYVH6_)

```
for file in glob.glob("images/*.jpg")):
        img = cv2.imread(file)  


        #edge detection
        canny = auto_canny(img)


        #Dilation(Morphological function to increase edge width)
        img_dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, (3,3), iterations = 1)


        #Gaussian Blur to blur the edges to remove noise
        mask= ndimage.gaussian_filter(img_dilate, sigma=5)
        mask[mask< 30] = 0
        mask[(mask>= 30) & (mask< 70)] = 30
        mask[(mask>= 70) & (mask< 110)] = 110
        mask[mask> 110] = 255



#       Retrieve regions from original images
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)
        mask_inv= cv2.bitwise_not(mask)


        #adding the extracted regions to background image
        main_ = cv2.bitwise_and(im_1, im_1, mask = mask_inv)
        result = cv2.add(main_, res)

        cv2.imshow("result",mask)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

        image_1.append(mask) #list of masks
        image_2.append(res) #list of all extracted regions


for i in range(0,len(image_1)):
    max_ = np.maximum.reduce([image_1[i]])
cv2.imshow("max",max_)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Update**

```
max_img = np.zeros((image_1[0].shape[:3]),dtype=np.uint8)
max_img = np.maximum(max_img,image_1)
cv2.imshow("max",max_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Using this update section, I ran into the `error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat`

Comment: np.maximum() requires 2 arrays. You only use one. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html. If you want the maximum value from any given array, then use np.max(). It only uses one array and finds the largest values in the array. If you are trying to compute the pixel-by-pixel maximum of two images, then use np.maximim()

Comment: @fmw42 I tried using np.maximum() but it returned an error: invalid number of arguments

Comment: @fmw42 In my code where I am using ```np.maximum.reduce``` I think it is just returning me the result from the last list item in image_3. What I want is to compare all the list items and give back the maximum pixels from all images

Comment: I am not an expert on .reduce. But I know that np.maximum compares two images at a time. So I believe you need to do the compares as follows. Create a zero image of the same size. Then get the maximum between each image with the result from the previous maximum. That is, maximage = np.maximum(maximage, image_1), where the first maximage is a zero filled image.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried it using np.maximum() and I got the ```error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat```. I'll update how I tried that

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html for arguments. Are you images all the same size. If not, then np.maximum will not work. You will have to crop them to the size of the smallest in each dimension. Are all your images of the same dtype?

Comment: @fmw42 yes they are of same type and same size. I have tried iterating over the images and adding the maximum to a zero image but at the end when I am trying to display it, it return the maximum of mask from the last image and not all the images.

Comment: I suggest that you test small pieces of code such as a simple maximum of two images. Once you get that working, then check your images to be sure they are all the same size and integrate the code into your code. Small unit tests help you learn the software and help you debug code.

Comment: Are they the same dtype and channels as your zero initial image?

Comment: @fmw42 yes they are the same dtype 'uint8' and same channels '3'

Comment: I do not understand your code in your function. You are appending the images vertically. So your image_1 gets larger in dimensions each time. Then I do not understand image_1[0].shape[:3] and how that relates to the dimension as you append. Sorry, I do not have time to rewrite your code.

Comment: Check the shape of your masks to be sure they are not one channel.

Comment: @fmw42 ok I'll check the mask shapes. Thanks for your time

Comment: Your code does not make sense to me. Why are you appending and not just doing the maximum inside your first loop once you have each mask. In the loop, read the image, create the mask and then simply get the maximum of the current mask with the previous maximum result. Are you trying to get the maximum of the masked images or the masks themselves?

Comment: @fmw42 I want to have all masks separately so that I can use them later. That is why I am appending them. And how to check them while in the for loop because in the first iteration there will only be one mask and what do I compare it to find the maximum?

Comment: Well then I do not understand your question. You asked how to get the maximum value pixel-by-pixel from all the masks. Is that not correct? Also your masks are not binary. They have several values in them. So your statement about binary masks is not accurate. Please show code pertinent to your question. See the help section of this forum about presenting minimum verifiable code.

Comment: @fmw42 Can you please suggest on how to find the maximum for the 1st iteration where I only have one mask and nothing to compare it with? I mean for image 1 when I am creating the mask, what do I compare it with to find the maximum?

Comment: As I said before, create an image of zeros of the same shape as your masks and use that for the the comparison. Again, I suggest you write a simple script that will compare two masks to get the maximum. The try repeat with one image and the image of zeros to get that working. Then loop over each mask after initializing with the zeros image. Did you check the shape of your masks and of your zeros image to be sure they are the same?

Comment: @fmw42 yes they are the same shape (750,1000)

Comment: But what about number of channels. See my example below. I created a 3 channel zero image, since my masks were binary 0 and 255, but had 3 equal channels. Perhaps all your masks are single channel. That is why I asked before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of getting the maximum value pixel-by-pixel of 4 binary mask images using Python/OpenCV/Numpy

4 Masks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read masks
mask1 = cv2.imread('mask1.png')
mask2 = cv2.imread('mask2.png')
mask3 = cv2.imread('mask3.png')
mask4 = cv2.imread('mask4.png')

# check shape so that image of zeros (below) is created compatible
print(mask1.shape)

# make list
masks = [mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4]

# initialize maximum array to zeros
image_max = np.full((mask1.shape), (0,0,0), dtype=np.uint8)

# get maximum pair-wise from mask and previous maximum image
for mask in masks:
    image_max = np.maximum(image_max, mask)

# show results
cv2.imshow('maximum', image_max)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save results
cv2.imwrite('mask1-4max.png', image_max)
```

[image]

Comment: May I recommend `np.zeros(mask1.shape, dtype=np.uint8)` or even `np.zeros_like(mask1)`

Comment: `@alkasm` Thanks for the suggestions. Lots of ways to "skin the cat". But I am open to learning different ways, especially ones that are more efficient or elegant.